# Where condition to find record by mutliple params in assocaited model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to find an associated models record by multiple params passed in a form to create a user_product which associates with the product model.

Create method in controller:

```
  @user_product = UserProduct.new(user_product_params)
  @product = Product.where(style_id: @user_product.style_id).where(size: @user_product.size).where(color: @user_product.color).where(country: @user_product.country)
  @user_product.product_id = @product.id
```

**Models:**

**Product:**

```
  belongs_to :category, foreign_key: :category_id, class_name: "Category"
  belongs_to :style, foreign_key: :style_id, class_name: "Style"
  belongs_to :user_products
```

**UserProduct:**

```
  has_one :product
  has_many :orders
```

The form passes:
size, color, style_id, category_id

I keep getting the error:

```
undefined method `id' for #<Product::ActiveRecord_Relation:x> Did you mean? ids
```

Everything is being passed but the product_id though.

How can I find the product_id by using the multiple params passed in the form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`where` returns an array records but you are looking for a single record only. You can use `find_by` which returns the first record matching the conditions (or nil, if none was found):

```
@product = Product.find_by(
  style_id: @user_product.style_id,
  size:     @user_product.size,
  color:    @user_product.color,
  country:  @user_product.country
)
if @product
  @user_product.product_id = @product.id
else
  # add an error if the product is not found,
  # or do something else
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is quite clear from the error message. As `undefined method 'id' for #<Product::ActiveRecord_Relation:x> Did you mean? ids` denotes, you don't have one product with an `id` but a relation of - possibly - multiple products. So you might want to try: `@product.first.id` instead.

Comment: Thanks.  Ok so that did work.  However what confuses me is that each record is unique in the sense that no record in the Product model will ever have all attributes matching  another record in the Product model.  So, therefor shouldn't the .where find the one and only without needing to use first?  Or am i missing something about this and if so can you explain a bit

Comment: If you use a `.where()` clause to find an entity, you typically don't have just one object that matches your search but multiple. That's why an `ActiveRecord_Relation` is returned. When you know beforehand there will be only one possible element to be returned you should use the [`.find_by` methods](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find_by) as @max already suggested.

Comment: @uno you should also put model validations and database constraints  for this uniqeness requirement

Answer (score 0):

As you are using where query it will return ActiveRecord::Relation , which is in form of array even if it returns single record. so your @product variable has result in Array form, if you are sure that you will only get one record from this query you should use `.take` method , but i suggest you use `.find_by` method for finding the record.

Answer (score 0):

`where` clause return `ActiveRecord` object(s) in a `ActiveRecord_Relation` that is a kind of `Array` even there is a single record. Try this

```
@user_product = UserProduct.new(user_product_params)
@products = Product.where(style_id: @user_product.style_id, size: @user_product.size, color: @user_product.color, country: @user_product.country)
@user_product.product_id = @products.first.id
```

Hope you find this helpful !!!

Answer (score 0):

where condition give you the result in array.

Try this

```
@product.first.id
```